# Python loop not fully respecting a set rule

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I am looking to flag emails based on the sender on a shared outlook mailbox as quick as possible.

```py
#imports:
import time
from time import strftime
import pandas as pd, win32com.client as client
from win32.com.client import Dispatch

#importing the excel file that contains email addresses and corresponding flags:
df_excel = pd.read_excel(r'\\user\...\addresses.xlsx')
#adding both columns as lists:
df_excel_mail = df_excel['mail'].tolist();df_excel_flag = df_excel['flag'].tolist()
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
main_account = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
folder_inbox = main_account.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Test']
folder_inbox_WIP = main_account.Folders['Inbox'].Folders['Test'].Folders['WIP']

while True:
    time.sleep(0)
    messages = folder_inbox.Items.Count
    if messages > 0:
        for i in reversed(range(0,messages)):
            message = folder_inbox.Item[i]
            for y, z, in zip(df_excel_mail,df_excel_flag)
                if message.Categories == '' and y == message.SenderEmailAddress
                    message.Categories = z
                    message.Save
                    message.Move(folder_inbox_WIP)

    messages_v2 = folder_inbox_WIP.Items.Count
    if folder_inbox_WIP .Items.Count > 0:
        for ii in reversed (range(0,messages_v2)):
            message_v2 = folder_inbox_WIP[ii]
            message_v2.Move(folder_inbox)

    if strftime('%H, %M, %N') >= strftime('18:00:00')
        break
```

my addresses.xlsx sheet looks like that:

| mail | flag |
| --- | --- |
| aaa.bbb@mail.com | red color |
| ccc.ddd@outlook.com | green color |
| ... | ... |
| eee.fff@client.com |  |
| ... | ... |

When an email address is available in the df_excel_mail list but corresponding flag color is missing in the df_excel_flag list. some emails are sent to WIP folder anyway and flagged as #QNAN.

How is this possible when the following code is supposed to prevent that to happen ?

```
if message.Categories == '' and y == message.SenderEmailAddress
```

Comment: first of it is certainly "respecting" whatever You have set there, have You checked what those variables are before evaluating them?

Comment: `message.Categories`  is the flag/category attributed to an email  in Outlook
`message.SenderEmailAddress` is the email address stored in the excel sheet that I am looking to match with the email currently being scanned for potential flagging

Comment: check individually what they get evaluated to

Comment: not sure I am getting your right but I did run a bunch of test prior to this loop to test each feature and control it individually.
`message.Categories can be = ''`
 if no flag assigned or to 'red color', 'green color', ... it works also with custom nammed categories.
message.SenderEmailAddress is equal to address for current email being scanned by the loop
y is equal to the mail column in the excel sheet

Comment: I guess those emails are strings but if python says they are not the same it means they are not the same, it could be some escaped character or sth like a newline that is making it not eval those both strings as both equal and to True

Comment: I understand from your comment that it might be related to format missmatch but I have no idea how to fix this or check further if you have an idea I would love to try it

Comment: try maybe using `y.strip() == message.SenderEmailAddress.strip()` because maybe it helps also it could be that `message.Categories` is not empty string but sth else

Comment: default value for message.Categories is `''` I checked it by priting message categories to an email not flagged
I tried adding the .strip() but it's not fixing the problem

Comment: message.Categories works to flag a mail but I just noticed that it doesn't seem to "read" the current flag value ...

Comment: well I don't know much about that module however I can tell You that python works as it should and there is no issue with that, the issue is that You expect it to do one thing but it doesn't because the You have made some mistake or more like the computer is not smart enough to understand what You want so it needs precision, anyhow try debuggin using `print()` and print out those values but beware that some escaped stuff will not show up when printing strings in terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to 'NaN' values in the dataframe I used .notna() to fix it